# Get json data with Goutte/Guzzle Client

Tags: php, http, web-crawler, guzzle, goutte

Trying to get json data with Guzzle Client (`@var Goutte\Client $client`)

```
$request = $client->getClient()->createRequest('GET', 'http://.../api'); 
$response = $request->send();
$json_data = $response->json();
```

Error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Type error: Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array,
string given, called in /var/www/.../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 87
```

Trying with Crawler

```
$crawler = $client->request("GET", "http://.../api");
$json_data = $crawler->text();
```

Error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
The current node list is empty.
```

**Edit**

See `Federkun`'s comment.

Solution:

```
$json_data = $client->getResponse()->getContent();
```

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($client->getResponse()->getContent());`?

Comment: This output is api I want :D Thanks!